Multiple versions of the emoji font are installed on your PC
When I open the emoji popup in Windows 11 (via the WIN+. shortcut), I get the following warning:

Multiple versions of the emoji font (Segoe UI Emoji) are installed on your PC. This may cause an issue with displaying emoji.


Browsing the available emojis, I notice that some are not displayed correctly. I don't know if it's related:

If I consult the list of fonts installed on my PC, I see multiple fonts named "Segoe", but I don't see any duplicate:

Should I remove one of those fonts in order to solve the issue? Which one(s)?
Or, can I somehow reset those fonts? E.g. delete all "Segoe" fonts and the let Windows reinstall them automatically?
Edit: as requested in comments, here's a screenshot of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts regedit key:

Also, my Windows information:
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
Installed on    18/03/2023
OS build    22631.3737
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1009.0


What version of Windows 11 are you using exactly?  Do you have an Insider Preview build installed? Try Control Panel --> Fonts --> Font settings --> Restore default font settings. Post a screenshot of RegEdit showing the following key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts make sure the Segoe UI Emoji keys are visible

@Ramhound Windows 11 Pro, 23H2. No I don't have Insider Preview installed. I have updated my post with the requested screenshot and full Windows specifications. As for the "restore default font settings" button, as far as I can tell it only makes sure that the "Hide fonts based on language settings" option on the same page is checked. It wasn't before, it is now, but I doubt it's relevant to the issue (the warning message is still present).

From this site:
Option 1: Restore Default Font Settings
1 . Open Control Panel and go to Fonts > Font Settings, then click Restore default font settings.
Option 2: Uninstall the duplicate SegoeUI Symbol font from your UserData folder
Window's default fonts should all be stored in C:\Windows\Fonts, and you cannot install duplicate fonts to this folder. If a duplicate font exists, it will be in your personal AppData folder, and you can delete it from there.

Open an elevated cmd/PowerShell window, navigate to C:\Users%user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts
Delete the fonts seguiemj.ttf and seguisym.ttf, if they exist.

UPDATE: Note that even with an elevated prompt you may not be able to delete these files via CMD/PS. If this is the case, you may need to use Safe Mode or a 3rd party unlocker/force delete tool.

Thanks. As far as I can tell, the first point (restore default font settings) only makes sure that "Hide fonts based on language settings" on the same page is checked. I don't think it's relevant (I've done it anyway).
As for the second point, I do indeed find seguisym.ttf and seguiemj.ttf in my User folder. However Windows won't let me delete them, saying that it is used by another process (System) or that "Access to path is denied". Using an elevated cmd or PowerShell prompt did not help, even with del /f filename. I'll try and use some third-party software such as LockHunter.

Use Safe Mode perhaps?

LockHunter did the job, although it requested that I restart Windows for it to be able to delete the files. They are now gone, and the warning in the emoji popup is also gone. Problem solved AFAICT. Thanks again. :) I didn't know about this secondary Fonts folder.

Me neither until I searched this error yesterday. Just for your own information I basically searched your question title and found this good result from the very reputable elevenforum.
